# How should I start a new Activity, after the application is done fetching and passing the fetched data to it?

Tags: java, android, database, android-intent, android-asynctask

In my app, I use a Contacts database and display those contacts using a `RecyclerView` . When I click on a contact, I want to fetch its data from the tables in the DB, and load them in a new Activity, `ContactCard`. I have an AsyncTask() which fetches the `PhoneNumber` objects that match the selected `contactId`, but I will also need to retrieve the `Address` and `Email` objects from the other tables.

I would like to be able to start the activity after all the relevant data is fetched, and I tried doing this in the activity with the Contacts `RecyclerView`, but the application crashes as the data has not been fetched yet.

I can call the new activity using an intent, but how can I ensure data from different tables is fetched first, before I start the new activity (which effectively displays this data)?

Some of my code:

```
public class PhoneNumberRepository {

    private WorksideDatabase worksideDatabase;
    private List<PhoneNumber> returnedNumbers;
    private Context mContext;

    public PhoneNumberRepository(Context context) {
        String DB_NAME = "workside_database";
        worksideDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, WorksideDatabase.class, DB_NAME).build();
        mContext = context;
    }

    public List<PhoneNumber> fetchPhoneNumbers(final int id) {

        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<PhoneNumber>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<PhoneNumber> doInBackground(Integer... ids) {

                returnedNumbers = worksideDatabase.phoneNumberDao().getPhoneNumbersById(id);

                System.out.println(returnedNumbers);

                for (PhoneNumber pn : returnedNumbers) {
                    System.out.println("Number: " + pn.getPhoneNumber());
                }

                return returnedNumbers;
            }

            // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<PhoneNumber> result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                System.out.println("Entered onPostExecute of fetchPhoneNumbers");

                //                for (PhoneNumber pn : result) {
                //                    Toast.makeText(mContext, pn + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //                }
            }
        }.execute();

        return returnedNumbers;
    }

    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers(int id) {
        return fetchPhoneNumbers(id);
    }
}
```

ContactsFragment:

```
     adapter.setOnItemClickListener(
                contact -> {
     Intent viewContact = new Intent(getActivity(), WorksideContactCard.class);
     viewContact.putExtra(WORKSIDE_CONTACT, contact);

     PhoneNumberRepository phoneNumberRepository =
         new PhoneNumberRepository(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

     List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumberList;

     phoneNumberList = phoneNumberRepository.getPhoneNumbers(contact.getId());

     ArrayList<PhoneNumber> arrlistPhoneNumbers =
                                new ArrayList<>(phoneNumberList);
                        viewContact.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                                WORKSIDE_CONTACT_PHONE_NO, arrlistPhoneNumbers);

      startActivity(viewContact);
}
```

Comment: post the crash log from logcat

Comment: @karan Well, I have fixed that. Essentially I was trying to use the List<PhoneNumber> variable before the AsyncTask() was finished fetching the data.

Comment: is your question answered then?

Comment: @karan apologies, I've re-phrased my question to make it clearer. I need to ensure that data from different tables is fetched first, before I start a new activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this when you click on an item start the asyntask like this

```
 adapter.setOnItemClickListener(
                contact -> {
     PhoneNumberRepository phoneNumberRepository =
     new PhoneNumberRepository(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

 List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumberList;

 phoneNumberRepository.getPhoneNumbers(contact.getId());

}
```

and change your PhoneNumberRepository to this class

```
public class PhoneNumberRepository {

        private WorksideDatabase worksideDatabase;
        private List<PhoneNumber> returnedNumbers;
        private Context mContext;

        public PhoneNumberRepository(Context context) {
            String DB_NAME = "workside_database";
            worksideDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, WorksideDatabase.class, DB_NAME).build();
            mContext = context;
        }

        public void fetchPhoneNumbers(final int id) {

            new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<PhoneNumber>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<PhoneNumber> doInBackground(Integer... ids) {

                    returnedNumbers = worksideDatabase.phoneNumberDao().getPhoneNumbersById(id);

                    System.out.println(returnedNumbers);

                    for (PhoneNumber pn : returnedNumbers) {
                        System.out.println("Number: " + pn.getPhoneNumber());
                    }

                    return returnedNumbers;
                }

                // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<PhoneNumber> result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
 Intent viewContact = new Intent(context, WorksideContactCard.class);
    ArrayList<PhoneNumber> arrlistPhoneNumbers =
                                new ArrayList<>(result);
                        viewContact.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                                WORKSIDE_CONTACT_PHONE_NO, arrlistPhoneNumbers);

      context.startActivity(viewContact);
                    System.out.println("Entered onPostExecute of fetchPhoneNumbers");


                }
            }.execute();

        }

        public void getPhoneNumbers(int id) {
            return fetchPhoneNumbers(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes probably this is what I need to do. Create the intent in `onPostExecute` and in there fetch the data for the Contact, PhoneNumber, Email and Address objects before displaying the contact's data.

Answer (score 0):

store the contacts in a list in the ***doInBackground()*** method and start an intent to the new activity in the ***onPostExecute()*** method and with this intent pass the list of contacts as intent.extra() variables, retrieve and use them in the called activity.

Answer (score 0):

Change your repository class to something like this

```
public class PhoneNumberRepository {

    private WorksideDatabase worksideDatabase;
    private List<PhoneNumber> returnedNumbers;
    private Context mContext;
    private boolean dataDownloaded;

    public PhoneNumberRepository(Context context) {
        String DB_NAME = "workside_database";
        worksideDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, WorksideDatabase.class, DB_NAME).build();
        mContext = context;
    }

    public List<PhoneNumber> fetchPhoneNumbers(final int id) {

        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<PhoneNumber>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<PhoneNumber> doInBackground(Integer... ids) {

                returnedNumbers = worksideDatabase.phoneNumberDao().getPhoneNumbersById(id);

                System.out.println(returnedNumbers);

                for (PhoneNumber pn : returnedNumbers) {
                    System.out.println("Number: " + pn.getPhoneNumber());
                }

                return returnedNumbers;
            }

            // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(List<PhoneNumber> result) {
                //set flag to false when download starts
               dataDownloaded = false;
            } 

            // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object obj) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                //set flag to true once download completes, you can also check if response is null and update it accordingly 
                dataDownloaded = true;

                System.out.println("Entered onPostExecute of fetchPhoneNumbers");

                //                for (PhoneNumber pn : result) {
                //                    Toast.makeText(mContext, pn + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //                }
            }
        }.execute();

        return returnedNumbers;
    }

    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers(int id) {
        return fetchPhoneNumbers(id);
    }

    public boolean isDataDownloaded(int id) {
        return dataDownloaded;
    }
}
```

Use this function in `onItemClick()` whether your data is downloaded or not

```
if(phoneNumberRepository.isDataDownloaded()) {
   //code to fetch data from phonenumberrepo and start activity
}
```

Comment: Currently I have no issue with getting a null contact. The issue arises because I have separate tables for contacts, and info such as "phone numbers", "emails" and "addresses", which are stored in separate tables. Retrieving the contact itself is okay, but I will also need to retrieve the associated phone numbers, emails and addresses.

Comment: @George is the data coming from your local db?

Comment: Yes, and the repository class fetches the data properly.

Comment: hm okay, but if I call `if(phoneNumberRepository.isDataDownloaded())` in `onItemClick()` surely it will execute before the data is fetched, hence dataDownloaded will always be false? I could give it a try if you believe otherwise.

Comment: You can show the appropriate message that data is being downloaded, and when that is completed and user clicks on item it will take him to next activity with data.